# compare 2 excel columns with data in adjacent columns

Tags: excel

I have seen a few answers which were close to what I am looking for, but can't quite figure it out. I apologize as I am not a programmer, but am tasked with these types of things periodically.

I have a spreadsheet with data in multiple rows. I would like to compare column A with C and have them align, and then the data in B move with column A. (I can rearrange the columns if need be to make this work.
I have this:

```
Inventory ID#   count   Original ID#    vendor      item number
1234            2     1000              vendor 1    1234566
1456            1     1234              vendor 2    546564
7000            3     1456              vendor 3    af4566
                      2003              vendor 4    56778
                      7000              vendor 1    788asd
```

What I want it to look like is after:

```
Inventory ID#   count   Original ID#    vendor      item number
                        1000            vendor 1    1234566
1234            2       1234            vendor 2    546564
1456            1       1456            vendor 3    af4566
                        2003            vendor 4    56778
7000            3       7000            vendor 1    788asd
```

I have tried macros, and `VLOOKUP`, but can't figure out how to have the count move with the **inventory ID #** Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data starts from cell `A1`, insert 2 columns `C and D` like below,
[image]

Enter the below formula in cell `C2` and drag it right to `column D` and then down throughout the range,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:A,MATCH($E2,$A:$A,0),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

[image]

You can then copy-pastespecial Column `C and D` to `A and B` and delete `C and D`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your data starts in `Sheet1!A1`

Move the `Invenotry ID#` and `count` columns to a different sheet (say, `Sheet2`).  Then replace the value in cells A2 with the following:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C2,Sheet2!$A:$B,1,FALSE),"")
```

and similar for cell B2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")
```

Fill it down.  The `VLOOKUP` will place your id's and counts in the right rows, and the `IFERROR( ... ,"")` part will put a blank string where there is no match, so it will look like you desired table

Comment: PERFECT PERFECT PERFECT! Thank you very much. I knew I was close, but couldn't quite get there. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I can help. Please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark beneath the votes on my question